# Sequencing an HList

Tags: scala, shapeless

Given a Shapeless HList where every list element shares the same type constructor, how can the HList be sequenced?

For example:

```
def some[A](a: A): Option[A] = Some(a)
def none[A]: Option[A] = None

val x = some(1) :: some("test") :: some(true) :: HNil
val y = sequence(x) // should be some(1 :: "test" :: true :: HNil)

def sequence[L <: HList : *->*[Option]#λ, M <: HList](l: L): Option[M] =
  ???
```

I tried to implement sequence like this:

```
object optionFolder extends Poly2 {
  implicit def caseOptionValueHList[A, B <: HList] = at[Option[A], Option[B]] { (a, b) =>
    for { aa <- a; bb <- b } yield aa :: bb
  }
}

def sequence[L <: HList : *->*[Option]#λ, M <: HList](l: L): Option[M] = {
  l.foldRight(some(HNil))(optionFolder)
}
```

But that does not compile:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter folder: shapeless.RightFolder[L,Option[shapeless.HNil.type],SequencingHList.optionFolder.type]
```

Any tips on implementing this for either a specific example like Option or for an arbitrary Applicative?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You were pretty close—you just need to make sure you have the extra bit of evidence that it's asking for:

```
def sequence[L <: HList : *->*[Option]#λ, M <: HList](l: L)(implicit
  folder: RightFolder[L, Option[HNil], optionFolder.type]
) = l.foldRight(some(HNil: HNil))(optionFolder)
```

Or, if you want something more general, and have an applicative implementation like this:

```
trait Applicative[F[_]] {
  def ap[A, B](fa: => F[A])(f: => F[A => B]): F[B]
  def point[A](a: => A): F[A]
  def map[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B] = ap(fa)(point(f))
}

implicit object optionApplicative extends Applicative[Option] {
  def ap[A, B](fa: => Option[A])(f: => Option[A => B]) = f.flatMap(fa.map)
  def point[A](a: => A) = Option(a)
}
```

You can write:

```
object applicativeFolder extends Poly2 {
  implicit def caseApplicative[A, B <: HList, F[_]](implicit
    app: Applicative[F]
  ) = at[F[A], F[B]] {
    (a, b) => app.ap(a)(app.map(b)(bb => (_: A) :: bb))
  }
}

def sequence[F[_]: Applicative, L <: HList: *->*[F]#λ, M <: HList](l: L)(implicit
  folder: RightFolder[L, F[HNil], applicativeFolder.type]
) = l.foldRight(implicitly[Applicative[F]].point(HNil: HNil))(applicativeFolder)
```

And now you can sequence lists, etc., as well (assuming you have the appropriate instances).

---

Update: Note that I've omitted the return type annotation for `sequence` in both cases here. If we put it back in, the compiler chokes:

```
<console>:18: error: type mismatch;
 found   : folder.Out
 required: F[M]
```

This is because the `RightFolder` instance carries around its return type as an abstract type member. We know it's `F[M]` in this case, but the compiler doesn't care about what we know.

If we want to be able to  be explicit about the return type, we can use the `RightFolderAux` instance instead:

```
def sequence[F[_]: Applicative, L <: HList: *->*[F]#λ, M <: HList](l: L)(implicit
  folder: RightFolderAux[L, F[HNil], applicativeFolder.type, F[M]]
): F[M] =
  l.foldRight(implicitly[Applicative[F]].point(HNil: HNil))(applicativeFolder)
```

Note that `RightFolderAux` has an extra type parameter, which indicates the return type.

Comment: Thanks! I tried providing the implicit RightFolder before posting but ran in to the exact error you pointed out above (required `F[M]` but found `folder.Out`). The RightFolderAux makes that clear.

Comment: I just tried the sequence implementation with Shapeless 2.0 and get this error: Error:(41, 36) could not find implicit value for parameter folder: shapeless.ops.hlist.RightFolder[L,Option[shapeless.HNil],optionFolder.type]
    l.foldRight(Option(HNil: HNil))(optionFolder)
                                   ^

Comment: @ChanningWalton: Is there an error before that one? Did you import `shapeless.ops.hlist.RightFolder`? It works for me in 2.0.0.

Comment: I'm unable to get this to work with shapeless 1.2.4; It seems to get hung up on the type inference of the output type for the RightFolderAux. If I supply the type parameters explicitly, then it works. https://gist.github.com/timcharper/df19933d06601f3ac834

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use [kittens](https://github.com/milessabin/kittens/blob/master/core/src/test/scala/cats/sequence/sequence.scala) `cats.sequence`

```
import cats.implicits._
import cats.sequence._
import shapeless._

val f1 = (_: String).length
val f2 = (_: String).reverse
val f3 = (_: String).toDouble

val f = (f1 :: f2 :: f3 :: HNil).sequence
assert( f("42.0") == 4 :: "0.24" :: 42.0 :: HNil)
```

The example sequenced against Function but you can use anything that has an cats `Applicative` instance.