# Scala: Class of Options to Option of Class

Tags: scala

Is there a neat way to convert a class that only has `Option` fields to the a similar class wrapped in an option?

```
case class Data(a: Option[Int], b: Option[Int])
case class DataX(a: Int, b: Int)

def convert(data: Data): Option[DataX] = 
  for {
    alpha <- data.a
    beta <- data.b
  } yield DataX(alpha, beta)
```

It's just tedious typing and it seems like there should/could be a standard way, e.g. in Cats or Scalaz?!

Comment: I would suspect you are taking about PartialFunction lift and unlift: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Function$.html hope that helps

Comment: @Pavel I'm not quite sure I follow.

Comment: There is a standard scala functionality which wraps function result with Option and back, not sure if this is fit to your use case

Comment: if you want to go very generic (convert any case class has only `Option` fields, to  another case class with the same shape with complete type safety), you can write it with shapeless. Basically what you would need to do is `case class Data` -> `HList : *->*[Option]#λ` -> fold: `Option[HList]` -> `Generic.materialize[DataX]`. If you want to go for it, I can try to implement it in an answer. But in general it is not some standard scalaZ way :)

Comment: @ISeeVoices Can you please do that? I would really much appreciate this as I believe `shapeless` is the way to go to solve the problem as it is stated but I do not have the understanding of the library to actually come up with a solution.

Comment: can you please accept the answer if it answers your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're two small notes, before we jump into implementation.

1) With shapeless, you can convert any case class (or ADT) to its generic representation and back.
- If it is the case class - the generic representation will be `HList` 
- If it is the ADT (sealed trait/abstract class, with objects/case classes extending it) - the generic representation will be `Coproduct`

You can do such conversions, because they are isomorphic. Making such conversions is useful, because, `HList` - has properties of List, so you can do some nice stuff generically, such as mapping, folding, filtering and what not.

2) There's a abstraction in functional programming, called **Sequence** (or sometimes more generally Traversable Functor), that converts `F[G[A]]` to `G[F[A]]`, given `G` - is `Applicative`. So, for example, you can convert `List[Option[A]]` -> `Option[List[A]]`, or `Future[Either[?, A]]` to `Either[? Future[A]]` etc..  That is exactly what you want to achieve.

So the plan is:

1. Convert your case class to an `HList`, which consists of `Option`s in
   your case.
2. Use the Sequence operation on the `HList` (You would  get `Option[Hlist]`)
3. Map over `Option` to convert `HList` to your next case class representation.

I was about to implement the `Sequencer` myself, but found that part already implemented https://github.com/typelevel/shapeless-contrib (`"org.typelevel" %% "shapeless-scalaz" % "0.4.0"`). You can look through implementation of Sequencer, dont'be afraid, that at the beginning it would look like complete magic. After looking through several implementations of typeclasses for shapeless it starts making sense.

So the non-generic implementation is straightforward:

```
  import shapeless.Generic
  import scalaz.std.option.optionInstance
  import shapeless.contrib.scalaz.functions._

  def convertData(d: DataO): Option[Data] = {
    val x = Generic[DataO].to(d)
    val b = sequence(x)
    b.map(Generic[Data].from)
  }
```

This way we lost the genreality, so let's pull more types to the function.
We definetly need to provide 

input type: `I` and 

 output type : `O`.
Also we need to provide it is Generic represenation, which shapeless provides implicitly: `Generic.Aux[I, Ri]`
`Ri` - would be HList, consisting of `Option` in your case.
Then you need a Sequencer, which converts your `HList`, to `Option` of another `HList` (in general way, `HList of Fs` to `F[HList]`): `Sequencer.Aux[A, F[Ro]]`, where `F` - is an Functor.

So in the end the implementation is the following:.

```
  def convertData[I, Ri <: HList, F[_]: Functor, O, Ro](d: I)(implicit GI: Generic.Aux[I, Ri],  Se: Sequencer.Aux[Ri, F[Ro]], G: Generic.Aux[O, Ro]): F[O] = {
    val x = GI.to(d)
    val b = sequence(x)
    val y = Functor[F].map(b)(G.from)
    y
  }
```

Where, F - is any Applicative, not necessarily `Option`.
The problem is, that in the end, scala compiler is not able infer types nicely, and you need to infer them manually:

```
    case class DataO(i: Option[Int])
    case class Data(i: Int)
    convertData[DataO, shapeless.::[Option[Int], HNil], Option, Data, shapeless.::[Int, HNil]](
      DataO(Option(2))
    )
```

This happens because `Sequencer` works only with `HList`, but Generic representation can be also a `Coproduct`, so you need to provide the evidence, that your generic decomposition will be `HList`. Ideally you would need only to specify Output type and Applicative type:

```
convert[Data, Option](DataO(None)).
```

I still think that it is possible but I just did not figure out yet how. I will try to tweak it a little bit more, may be I find out the way.

**UPD**
I managed to do it, the end code is:

```
import scalaz.std.option.optionInstance
import shapeless.contrib.scalaz.functions._

case class DataO(i: Option[Int])    
case class Data(i: Int)

case class Converter[I, O]() {
  def convert[Ri <: HList, Ro, F[_]: Functor](d: I)(implicit GI: Generic.Aux[I, Ri], Se: Sequencer.Aux[Ri, F[Ro]], G: Generic.Aux[O, Ro]): F[O] = {
    val x = GI.to(d)
    val b = sequence(x)
    val y = Functor[F].map(b)(G.from)
    y
  }
}

//usage
Converter[DataO, Data].convert(DataO(Option(1)) // Some(Data(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer takes a bit from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16128064/5684257).

First off, this generalizes to every `Applicative` functor, so I won't use `Option` specifically except for examples. Secondly, this uses shapeless for all the `Generic`/`HList` goodies.

You want to `sequence` over `HList`s. This is implemented as a fold. This is the accumulating function:

```
// (a, b) => a :: b plus applicative and shapeless noise
object sequenceFold extends Poly2 {
  implicit def fold[A, B <: HList, F[_]: Applicative] = at[F[A], F[B]] { (fa, fb) =>
    fa.map { a: A => b: B => a :: b }.ap(fb)
  }
}
```

Then, `sequenceH`

```
def sequenceH[
  F[_]: Applicative,
  L <: HList,
  O <: HList
](l: L)(implicit
  restrict: UnaryTCConstraint[L, F], // All elements of L are F[something]
  folder: RightFolder.Aux[L, F[HNil], sequenceFold.type, F[O]] // evidence for fold
): F[O] = l.foldRight(Applicative[F].pure(HNil: HNil))(sequenceFold)(folder)
// This is rather painful to use, because type inference breaks down utterly
```

Now, we use `Generic` to drag this out of `HList`land. First, we need some relationship between `Data` and `DataX`, because otherwise we're looking up `DataX` from the `HList` `Int :: Int :: HNil`, and that doesn't work. In this case I think it's best to just parameterize `Data` over some constructor `F`, but typeclasses would work, too, I think:

```
case class DataF[F[_]](a: F[Int], b: F[Int])
type Data = DataF[Option]
type Id[X] = X
type DataX = DataF[Id]

def sequenceCase[
  D[F[_]], // Types like DataF
  F[_]: Applicative,
  IL <: HList,
  OL <: HList
](i: D[F])(implicit
  genI: Generic.Aux[D[F], IL], // D[F] <=> IL
  restrict: UnaryTCConstraint[IL, F], // All elements of IL <=> D[F] are F[something]
  folder: RightFolder.Aux[IL, F[HNil], sequenceFold.type, F[OL]], // Can sequence IL to O[OL]
  genO: Generic.Aux[D[Id], OL] // OL <=> D[Id]
): F[D[Id]] = sequenceH(genI.to(i))(Applicative[F], restrict, folder).map(genO.from)

// Type inference is fixed here
Seq(DataF[Option](None   , None   ),
    DataF[Option](Some(1), None   ),
    DataF[Option](None   , Some(1)),
    DataF[Option](Some(1), Some(1))
).map(sequenceCase(_))
// None, None, None, Some(DataF[Id](1, 1))
```

This works, but what if

```
case class DataF2[F[_]](a: F[Int], b: String)
// b is NOT in F
```

This gets complicated, because it's also possible to have

```
case class DataF3[F[_]](a: F[Int], b: Option[String])
```

and you don't really know what to do if `F = Option`, because it makes sense to get either `Option[Int :: Option[String]]` and `Option[Int :: String]`. I think I'd implement it by zipping the `HList`s for the two versions of the class together, then folding over the pairs to figure out how to get from one to the other. I won't implement it here, though.